# Find a value after a point or before a point

Tags: sql, decimal-point

Here is my query:

```
Select 23.25 from dual
```

How can I Select only 23 from this number or 25 from this number. I mean to find the value after a point or before a point i number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want FLOOR()?

```
SELECT         FLOOR(23.25) FROM dual
SELECT 23.25 - FLOOR(23.25) FROM dual
```

Comment: @AF. - Please don't edit, use comments.  Even though `*100` appears appropriate in this case, what if the next number is `23.267`?

Comment: `SELECT 23.25 - FLOOR(23.25) FROM dual` gives 0.25 not 25

Answer (score 0):

23 you can get using this :

```
Select floor(23.25) from dual;
```

and then 25 after the point you can get using this :

```
Select (23.25 - floor(23.25))*100 from dual;
```

Comment: Our answers were the same, and I just missed by seconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get 23 as a output we can use this query

```
SELECT FLOOR(23.25) FROM dual
```

& To get exact '25' as a output we can use this query

```
   SELECT FLOOR((23.25 - FLOOR(23.25))*100) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value **after** the decimal place (fraction part), you can use

```
SELECT 23.25 % 1 

-- Output
-- 0.25
```

To get the value **before** the decimal place (integer part) (assuming you are using SQL Server)

```
SELECT FLOOR(23.25)

-- Output
-- 23
```